How to focus border when typing and goes initial state when don't have text
I can't see my border when i try type something borderwidth and bordercolor not changing
struct PasswordTextField: TextFieldFactory {
    @State private var isTyping = false
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @Binding var text: String

    func createTextField(placeholder: String) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            SecureField(placeholder, text: $text)
                .clearButton(text: $text)
                .padding(.horizontal, 13)
                .padding(.vertical, 14)
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 14)
                        .fill(AppColors.light80)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 14)
                                .stroke(
                                    isTyping ? AppColors.dark100 : AppColors.light80,
                                    lineWidth: (
                                        isFocused || text.count > 0
                                    ) ? 1.2 : 0
                                )
                        )
                )
                .frame(width: 348, height: 52)
                .foregroundColor(AppColors.dark100)
                .font(Font.Everett.Regular.body)
                .focused($isFocused)
                .onChange(of: $text.wrappedValue) { _, newValue in
                    isTyping = !newValue.isEmpty
                }
                .onChange(of: isFocused) { _, focused in
                    if !focused {
                        isTyping = false
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

protocol TextFieldFactory {
    associatedtype TextFieldType: View
    func createTextField(placeholder: String) -> TextFieldType
}


i expect when i type my border goes 1.2 points and more darker color and goes initial state when textfield count 0

What is the point of this TextFieldFactory protocol? @State, @Binding etc only works in certain protocols that SwiftUI "knows about". You can't use them anywhere you like.

Ok, but what's point of border problem, i want know about that, if you know.
